# Published Shiny app has missing values in ggplot geom_line that are present in local R output

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shinyapps

I have a complete Shiny app that pulls data from an online database and outputs plots and tables that can be edited by selecting data locations and dates. When I run the app in R Studio, all elements are rendered perfectly. However, when I publish this same app to shinyapps.io, one of the plots does not render correctly.

Here is the output on shinyapps.io:

[image: ![Local App](Y:\Luke\Shiny\WQ_Dashboard\Resources\Help Image 1.jpg)]

And here is the local output in the R Studio window:

[image: Shinyapps.io Output]

As you can see, for some reason the dashed line geom for the stage elevation data in the TP & Stage tab is missing chunks of data. The data is present in the local output, in the shinyapps.io Stage Table below the plot tab, and in the Flow & Stage tab, which plots the same stage data (only with flow volumes instead of phosphorus concentrations). This happens for the same chunks of time in each year even if you expand the period of record to go further back.

Is there a common issue that would cause this? I am not even sure what code to change since it works perfectly as a local output. I suspect it might be some kind of graphical glitch, but I have republished the app to no avail.

Comment: Wild guess: Are these lacking data points newly generated and written to somewhere? If yes on shinyapps.io you can't  write on the server.

Comment: @TarJae all of the data is taken from the database at once. The missing data points are the same ones that are in the "Flow & Stage" plot and the Stage Table below the plots, they just won't render visually for some reason.

Comment: It would help to have a reproducible example to try out potential solutions and/or identify what's causing the problem. Making a pared down version of your app that replicates the problem might even uncover the sections of code that are creating the issue. At a minimum, can you post the code that extracts/subsets the data and your plotting code?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue myself.

Before, I was not using reactive expressions at all (I had just started experimenting with Shiny last week). After taking out the data cleaning and filtering expressions from inside each `renderPlot({})` function and putting them into reactive expressions for Flow, Stage, and Phosphorus data separately, the plots all render correctly.

Before:

```
server <- function(input, output, session){
  # Flow & Stage Plot
  output$flowstage = renderPlot({
    flow = flow.xtab %>%
      filter(Date >= input$POR[[1]] & Date <= input$POR[[2]], SITE %in% as.list(input$site1))
    stage = stage %>%
      filter(Date >= input$POR[[1]] & Date <= input$POR[[2]])
    dat = flow %>%
      left_join(stage, by = "Date")
    sec.axis.scaler = ifelse(input$stack == "Identity",
                             max(dat$fflow.cfs,na.rm=T)/max(dat$S333HW, na.rm=T)*0.8,
                             max(aggregate(dat$fflow.cfs, by = list(dat$Date), sum)$x, na.rm = T)/max(dat$S333HW, na.rm = T)*0.8)
    ggplot(dat) +
      scale_y_continuous(name = "Flow (cfs)",
                         sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~./sec.axis.scaler, name = "Stage (ft)")) +
      geom_area(aes(as.Date(Date), fflow.cfs, fill = SITE), alpha = 0.6, position = input$stack) +
      geom_line(aes(as.Date(Date), S333HW*sec.axis.scaler, color = "Stage"), color = "black", linetype = "dashed") +
      labs(title = 'Flow & S333HW Stage Data',
           y = 'Flow (cfs)',
           x = 'Date') +
      xlim(as.Date(input$POR[[1]]), as.Date(input$POR[[2]])) +
      theme_bw()
  })
  # TP & Stage Plot
  output$tpstage = renderPlot({
    tp = tp.xtab3 %>%
      filter(Date >= input$POR[[1]] & Date <= input$POR[[2]], SITE %in% as.list(input$site2)) %>%
      mutate(tp.ugL = tp.ugL*1000)
    stage = stage %>%
      filter(Date >= input$POR[[1]] & Date <= input$POR[[2]])
    dat = tp %>%
      left_join(stage, by = "Date")
    sec.axis.scaler = max(dat$tp.ugL,na.rm=T)/max(dat$S333HW, na.rm=T)*0.8
    ggplot(dat) +
      scale_y_continuous(name = "TP (ug/L)",
                         sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~./sec.axis.scaler, name = "Stage (ft)")) +
      geom_point(aes(as.Date(Date), tp.ugL, color = SITE), alpha = 0.6) +
      geom_line(aes(as.Date(Date), S333HW*sec.axis.scaler, color = "Stage"), color = "black", linetype = "dashed") +
      labs(title = 'TP & S333HW Stage Data',
           y = 'TP (ug/L)',
           x = 'Date') +
      xlim(as.Date(input$POR[[1]]), as.Date(input$POR[[2]])) +
      theme_bw()
  })
  # Flow & TP Plot
  output$flowtp = renderPlot({
    flow = flow.xtab %>%
      filter(Date >= input$POR[[1]] & Date <= input$POR[[2]], SITE %in% as.list(input$site1))
    tp = tp.xtab3 %>%
      filter(Date >= input$POR[[1]] & Date <= input$POR[[2]], SITE %in% as.list(input$site2)) %>%
      mutate(tp.ugL = tp.ugL*1000)
    dat = flow %>%
      full_join(tp, by = c("Date","SITE"))
    sec.axis.scaler = ifelse(input$stack == "Identity",
                             max(dat$fflow.cfs,na.rm=T)/max(dat$tp.ugL, na.rm=T)*0.8,
                             max(aggregate(dat$fflow.cfs, by = list(dat$Date), sum)$x, na.rm = T)/max(dat$tp.ugL, na.rm = T)*0.8)
    ggplot(dat) +
      scale_y_continuous(name = "Flow (cfs)",
                         sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~./sec.axis.scaler, name = "TP (ug/L)")) +
      geom_area(aes(as.Date(Date), fflow.cfs, fill = SITE), alpha = 0.6, position = input$stack) +
      geom_point(aes(as.Date(Date), tp.ugL*sec.axis.scaler, color = SITE), alpha = 0.6) +
      labs(title = 'Flow & TP Data',
           y = 'Flow (cfs)',
           x = 'Date') +
      xlim(as.Date(input$POR[[1]]), as.Date(input$POR[[2]])) +
      theme_bw()
  })
```

After:

```
server <- function(input, output, session){
  # Reactive functions for data subsets
  rflow = reactive({
    flow.xtab %>%
      filter(Date >= input$POR[[1]] & Date <= input$POR[[2]], SITE %in% as.list(input$site1)) %>%
      mutate(Date = as.Date(Date))
  })
  rstage = reactive({
    stage %>%
      filter(Date >= input$POR[[1]] & Date <= input$POR[[2]]) %>%
      mutate(Date = as.Date(Date))
  })
  rtp = reactive({
    tp.xtab3 %>%
      filter(Date >= input$POR[[1]] & Date <= input$POR[[2]], SITE %in% as.list(input$site2)) %>%
      mutate(tp.ugL = tp.ugL*1000, Date = as.Date(Date))
  })
  # Flow & Stage Plot
  output$flowstage = renderPlot({
    dat = rflow() %>%
      left_join(rstage(), by = "Date")
    sec.axis.scaler = ifelse(input$stack == "Identity",
                             max(dat$fflow.cfs,na.rm=T)/max(dat$S333HW, na.rm=T)*0.8,
                             max(aggregate(dat$fflow.cfs, by = list(dat$Date), sum)$x, na.rm = T)/max(dat$S333HW, na.rm = T)*0.8)
    ggplot(dat) +
      scale_y_continuous(name = "Flow (cfs)",
                         sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~./sec.axis.scaler, name = "Stage (ft)")) +
      geom_area(aes(as.Date(Date), fflow.cfs, fill = SITE), alpha = 0.6, position = input$stack) +
      geom_line(aes(as.Date(Date), S333HW*sec.axis.scaler, color = "Stage"), color = "black", linetype = "dashed") +
      labs(title = 'Flow & S333HW Stage Data',
           y = 'Flow (cfs)',
           x = 'Date') +
      xlim(as.Date(input$POR[[1]]), as.Date(input$POR[[2]])) +
      theme_bw()
  })
  # TP & Stage Plot
  output$tpstage = renderPlot({
    dat = rtp() %>%
      left_join(rstage(), by = "Date")
    sec.axis.scaler = max(dat$tp.ugL,na.rm=T)/max(dat$S333HW, na.rm=T)*0.8
    ggplot(dat) +
      scale_y_continuous(name = "TP (ug/L)",
                         sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~./sec.axis.scaler, name = "Stage (ft)")) +
      geom_point(aes(as.Date(Date), tp.ugL, color = SITE), alpha = 0.6) +
      geom_line(aes(as.Date(Date), S333HW*sec.axis.scaler, color = "Stage"), color = "black", linetype = "dashed") +
      labs(title = 'TP & S333HW Stage Data',
           y = 'TP (ug/L)',
           x = 'Date') +
      xlim(as.Date(input$POR[[1]]), as.Date(input$POR[[2]])) +
      theme_bw()
  })
  # Flow & TP Plot
  output$flowtp = renderPlot({
    dat = rflow() %>%
      full_join(rtp(), by = c("Date","SITE"))
    sec.axis.scaler = ifelse(input$stack == "Identity",
                             max(dat$fflow.cfs,na.rm=T)/max(dat$tp.ugL, na.rm=T)*0.8,
                             max(aggregate(dat$fflow.cfs, by = list(dat$Date), sum)$x, na.rm = T)/max(dat$tp.ugL, na.rm = T)*0.8)
    ggplot(dat) +
      scale_y_continuous(name = "Flow (cfs)",
                         sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~./sec.axis.scaler, name = "TP (ug/L)")) +
      geom_area(aes(as.Date(Date), fflow.cfs, fill = SITE), alpha = 0.6, position = input$stack) +
      geom_point(aes(as.Date(Date), tp.ugL*sec.axis.scaler, color = SITE), alpha = 0.6) +
      labs(title = 'Flow & TP Data',
           y = 'Flow (cfs)',
           x = 'Date') +
      xlim(as.Date(input$POR[[1]]), as.Date(input$POR[[2]])) +
      theme_bw()
  })
```

I guess this is a lesson to always streamline your code and eliminate repetitive expressions wherever possible!